# How to access a header member type without scope resolution operator in C++?

Tags: c++, scope-resolution

I am learning C++, this may be a silly question.

I want to create a class for common type definitons and using it in many cpp files by inluding.
Header is "CommonTypesCls.h":

```
class CommonTypesCls
{
public:     
    typedef unsigned int UINT32;
    typedef int INT32;
}
```

And I want to use these attributes in source.cpp like that:

```
#include "CommonTypesCls.h"
int main()
{    
    int a = sizeof(UINT32);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to using a inclueded class' member type without scope resolution?

Comment: I see no "attribute" in your code. Do you mean "member type"?

Comment: Yes, I mean member type.

Comment: Fixed size integer types are provided by `<stdint.h>`. The common convention in C++ is to reserve ALL UPPERCASE identifiers for macro symbols (though many beginners/novices and even some professionals do this, you misapplied a Java/Python convention to a language where it's not at all suitable). Anyway, please do post **real code**, not some "like that" pseudo-code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I think in this particular case it looks more like the misapplication of a C convention, or perhaps the bad influence of `<windows.h>` typedefs.

Comment: Make sure your header has header guards.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible unless you use a type alias.

```
using UINT32 = CommonTypesCls::UINT32;
```

But you shouldn't do that because a class is not a suitable place to collect type definitions.

Put them in the global scope or in a namespace instead.

Comment: definitely not in the global scope in a header file!

Answer (score 2):

Loooon ago, the C++ standard included **`namespace`** for exactly this purpose (btw, it appears you're re-inventing a wheel):

```
#include <cstdint>

namespace CommonTypesCls {
  using uint32 = std::uint32_t;
  using  int32 = std::int32_t;
}

int foo() {
  using namespace CommonTypesCls;
  uint32 a = 666;
}
```

If your types are specific to a particular class, for example dependent on a template parameters (such as `std::vector<>::value_type`), then you **must** use the scope resolution operator somewhere, but you can create an alias:

```
template<typename Container>
void bar(Container const&container)
{
  using value_type = typename Container::value_type;   // scope resolution
  value_type temporary_storage[4];
  for(auto const&x : container) {
    /* do something with x and using temporary_storage */
  }
}
```

However, when using `auto` variable declarations, it is often not necessary to explicitly specify the type.

Answer (score 1):

A class is generally the wrong way to provide common definitions: use a `namespace`.

Also, the particular definitions you appear to want, of fixed size integer types, are provided by `<stdint.h>`.

That said, you can use `public` and `protected` definitions from a class `C` unqualified in code in a class derived from `C`. But that would be using two generally wrong tools: a class to provide definitions, and inheritance to gain access. Still it can be appropriate in some cases, e.g. for providing access to the names in an `enum` type.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
#include "CommonTypesCls.h"
int main()
{
    typedef typename CommonTypesCls::UINT32 UINT32;
    int a = sizeof(UINT32);
    return 0;
}
```

Seriously though, not really.